# How to use Flow for heterogeneous traffic?

Tags: flow-project

Since sumo doesn't natively support heterogeneous traffic, but the published paper says Flow could be used for this type of traffic, I was wondering how this is done with Flow as there is nothing about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create heterogeneous traffic behavior by introducing different vehicle types with different behaviors. If you just have a single vehicle type, you can add random noise (drawn from some random distribution) to the microscopic models such as car-following and lane changing models.

Comment: Could we use this to model Asian style traffic, like where there are multiple cars in one lane, or would we have to use something like SiMTraM, and would it be possible to use SiMTram with Flow? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sumo supports heterogeneous traffic natively using the sublane model which is activated using the option `--lateral-resolution`, see https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/SublaneModel